# Prevent pushing up of printed multiline

Tags: python

When printing a multi line output rapidly for a ascii sidescroller game/animation the whole string gets rendered then pushed up one line for every frame. I know preventing this from happening is possible with a single line output using `"\r"` at the start of your string together with `print(text, end="", flush=True)` but this does not work for multiline.
How to make the output render smooth?
Thanks in advance!

Basic code:

```
while True:
    print("\n"*20) # Flush screen
    print(multiline_string)
    sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: It sounds like you want control sequences to move your cursor around (just as `\r` moves to the front of the current line, there are also control sequences available to move up to a prior line). The details depend on the user's terminal -- it's not the same sequence everywhere.

Comment: ...being able to abstract out this kind of difference between terminals is part of what the terminfo database and libraries that read it are there for.

Comment: See https://github.com/DirectXMan12/py-terminfo as an example of a native-Python library for figuring out what the control sequences are for the active terminal. Any of the many ncurses wrappers will do the job too. Picking one is a library recommendation question, and thus out-of-scope here.

Comment: (Also, some terminals allow double buffering, such that you can have one buffer displayed while you write to another; that, too, is something you need to read terminfo to be able to figure out the availability of, and also which precise control sequences to use).